# Make object spring managed

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, autowired

**How can I get an already existing object spring managed?** I would like to hook it up to `Springs AoP` capabilities using `aspectj`. I know this to be a challenge since `Spring AoP` uses dynamic proxies which probably are created along with the object.

### Why do I need this?

I have a *third-party* class which takes a constructor argument which is only known in *runtime*, 
hence it seems I cannot add it to my `applicationContext` or use springs `FactoryBean` interface for construction. **Is there any other way?**

I've already tried the following without great success:

```
Obj obj = new ThirdPartyObj("runtime constructor arg");
appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(obj, "Obj");
```

It *might* be spring-managed, but I still cannot use it to trigger aspects.

---

**[EDIT]** *axtavt* pointed out the problem is that I don't use the object returned from `initializeBean(..)`. Both mentioned approaches work, but only if:

- Using interface `ObjInterface obj = (ObjInterface) ac.getBean("obj", args);` or we will get a:

  `java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy28 cannot be cast to com.company.Obj`
- Not using interface but enable `CGLIB`. This requires a **non-private** default constructor, or we will get a:

  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given`

Comment: By "at runtime", do you mean "at method execution time", or "at startup time"?

Comment: @skaffman, at `method execution time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to trigger aspects using this (note that you need to use returned object which can be a proxy):

```
Obj obj = new ThirdPartyObj("runtime constructor arg");     
obj = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(obj, "Obj");
```

Another option is to declare it as a regular bean and pass the constructor argument via `getBean()`:

```
Obj obj = appContext.getBean("Obj", "runtime constructor arg");
```

Comment: This is the general answer to the question, however if the `interface` or `no-arg constructor` requirements are not met I think *skaffmans* approach is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Why not create a new class that wraps the functionality of `ThirdPartyObj`, and make *that* Spring-managed. Dependencies can then be injected into its fields and method parameters, and passed on the the instantiated `ThirdPartyObj`.

Comment: +1, this is the only approach I see possible if the `interface` or `no-arg constructor` requirements are not met.

Answer (score 0):

How about annotating the domain object with @Configurable annotation? I myself haven't tried it but seems like it might helpful in your scenario. AspectJ and Spring would create a managed object with attributes defined in the bean. The then created object instance can be used.

Comment: Absolutely, were it not for the constraint that the constructor argument is not known at application startup.