# aop on third party interface

Tags: spring, spring-aop

a third party library return object like below

```
@Autowired 
ThirdPartyFactory thirdPartyFactory;

TestInterface fromThirdParty =  thirdPartyFactory.getObject();  //this return TestInferfaceImpl

fromThirdParty.doSomething(someParameter);
```

how to do pointcut on TestInterface ?  Is it required to register  in xml file?

I tried point cut like below, but does not work

@Around("execution( * package.TestInterface.doSomething(..))")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options.

- Use pure AspectJ and skip Spring on this object.
- Wrap the object in a Spring bean as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288640/make-object-spring-managed).
- Use a combination of Spring and AspectJ as described [here](http://blog.frankel.ch/spring-can-inject-servlets-too).